# How do I launch the Edit screen after a new record has been created

Tags: flow

I am using the "Generate Orders" app from Salesforce Labs to generate an Order from an Opportunity. Everything works great except after the new Order is created I am still left on the Opportunity and must go to the Orders related list to open the newly created Order. The URL for the Generate Order button is pretty straight forward... and it uses a process Flow as well...

/flow/Opportunity_to_Order?OpptyID={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}

The goal is that once the new Order record has been created the user is presented with the Edit screen so that they can begin to fill out the Order.

Answer (score 0):

The URL will look like this:

```
/{!Order.Id}/e?retURL=/{!Order.Id}
```

Comment: Are you saying that I just replace the portion of my URL with this?  e.g.  /flow/Opportunity_to_Order?OpptyID={!Order.Id}&retURL=/{!Order.Id}

Comment: When you generate the order, your defined URL is fine and after that if user wants to edit the order, navigate the user to this URL.

Comment: Hi Santanu -  I'm not getting it!  The Flow generates the Order with data from the Opportunity... upon completion of the newly generated Order the user is left on the originating Opportunity screen.  It would seem to me that in order to navigate the user to the Order edit screen it would need to be a part of the Flow process ?  So I guess I'm asking how would I navigate the user to the Order as part of the Flow process?

Comment: I would suggest you to expose Order as related list under Opportunity, so user can view and edit the order.

Comment: Thanks Santanu - The Order is already a related object and visible on the Opportunity.  But that doesn't speak to the problem I am trying to solve.